Using Python for Monte Carlo simulation for predicting protein nucleation aggregation
I want to write a code for a Monte Carlo simulation to determine the maximum stable complexes in a protein nucleation reaction. Also, need to graph the results for the same.

Here is the problem statement:


Simulate the above system using MC and the kinetic rates as inputs. Calculate the probability
distribution of (histogram plots obtained from many runs of the simulation) for the number of
stable nucleation complexes at different time points. 20+5=25




Find out the distribution of sizes of stable nucleation complexes. 7




Vary ke and kf to show i) how the number of stable nucleation complexes vary with time ii)
how the maximum size of the stable nucleation complex varies with ke and kf. 4+4=8


I have tried doing the code myself but I can't find any viable solution
This is what I have done so far. I don't think it is correct.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define kinetic rates
ku = 0.8
kn_u = 0.45
kn_s = 0.55
ke = 0.05  # Decreased ke
kd = 0.25
kf = 0.1  # Decreased kf

# Define time range and initial conditions
t_max = 1000  # Maximum time
dt = 1  # Time step
t = np.arange(0, t_max, dt)
n_monomers = 1000  # Initial number of monomers
n_unstable = 0  # Initial number of unstable nucleation complexes
n_stable = 0  # Initial number of stable nucleation complexes

# Initialize list to store stable nucleation complexes
stable = [n_stable]

# Simulation loop
for t_step in t[1:]:
# Calculate rates
    r1 = ku * n_monomers  # Monomer to unstable nucleation
    r2 = kn_u * n_unstable  # Unstable nucleation to monomer
    r3 = kn_s * n_unstable  # Unstable nucleation to stable     nucleation
    r4 = ke * n_stable  # Stable nucleation to elongation
    r5 = kd * n_stable  # Stable nucleation to dissociation
    r6 = kf * n_stable  # Stable nucleation to fragmentation

    # Update monomer and nucleation complex counts
    dn_monomers = -r1 + r2
    dn_unstable = r1 - r2 - r3
    dn_stable = r3 - r4 - r5 - r6

    n_monomers += dn_monomers * dt
    n_unstable += dn_unstable * dt
    n_stable += dn_stable * dt

    # Store stable nucleation complexes
    stable.append(n_stable)

# Plot stable nucleation complexes
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(t, stable)
plt.title('Stable Nucleation')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Number of Stable Nucleation Complexes')
plt.show()


You haven't simulated anything here.  This is just a list of numbers (rather np array). MC uses an underlying distribution. What distribution is being considered here? Do you have a plot of observable data?
